# Как локализовать самописную тему для Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

1. В themes создал папку под тему fure.
2. Туда положил файлы темы (header.php, footer.php, index.php и т.д.)
3. Все работает.
4. В header.php нужно выводить надписи на разных языках, для этого создал конструкцию

```
<?php __( 'bla bla', 'pure' )?>
```

5. В этой папке имеется директория languages с файлом my-plugin.pot след. содержания:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-10-09T14:34:05+03:00\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"X-Generator: WP-CLI 2.4.0\n"
"X-Domain: languages\n"
```

6. Стоит плагин Loco Translate, который при переходе в Themes видит тему fure:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. При переходе в fure видно файл my-plugin.pot:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
8. При нажатии на него ожидаемо появляются пустые поля:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
9. Как мне теперь перевести фразу 'bla bla'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В папке language внутри вашей темы должны быть файлы c .po и .mo расширениями для каждого языка. К примеру для русского: my-plugin-ru_RU.mo и my-plugin-ru_RU.po. Для других языков суффиксы в названии файлов должны соответствовать другим языкам.

Comment: Файлы создал руками. Теперь появился Language русский. При переходе в него также пусто. Какие мои дальнейшие действия?

Comment: Файлы с расширением po - по-сути текстовые. Много ли в вашей теме строк для перевода? Все ли заполнены? Попробуйте их всё-таки открыть в программе poedit. Будет возможность проверить файл на ошибки.

Comment: Пока одна только строчка. В poedit открыл, ошибок никаких нет, пишет, что перевод отсутствует

Comment: Ребят, очень большая просьба помочь - проект не могу сдать

Comment: К слову. В моём случае файлы называются именно ru_RU.mo и ru_RU.po, так как они уже лежат в папке с темой.

Comment: Можно ещё вот так: в папку /wp-content/languages/themes положить оба файла с названиями fure-ru_RU.mo и fure-ru_RU.po То есть в общую папку языков и тем.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек! Так заработало

Comment: Остались мелочи - переводы для всех необходимых фраз затолкать в эти файлы, но помните, что .mo работает быстрее ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример самого начала файла темы, которую я написал, а затем и перевёл:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Le-Pare-Psy-Theme 1.0.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: Vladimir N. Smirnov <smirnov_1999@mail.ru>\n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: ru_RU\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.3\n"

#: le-phare-psy/archive.php:10
msgid "Archive of the day"
msgstr "Архив дня"

#: le-phare-psy/archive.php:13
msgid "Monthly Archives"
msgstr "Архив месяца"

#: le-phare-psy/archive.php:16
msgid "Archive for the year"
msgstr "Архив за год"
```

Обратите внимание, после заголовочной части темы,которая называется le-phare-psy, идут 3 фрагмента текста. В каждом из них в первой строке указан путь к файлу и строке, где нужен перевод, это для наглядности. Затем строчка на английском, именно она и присутствует в теме в том самом файле в той самой строке. Третьей строчкой идёт перевод фразы на русский.

Вы сами должны отловить такие фразы и сделать переводы на русский и прочие языки.

К примеру, в файле archive.php на 10 строчке есть фраза:

```
<?php _e('Archive of the day', 'le-phare-psy'); ?>
```

Вордпресс увидит эту строчку, полезет в папку language, найдёт файл для выбранного языка, у меня это русский и французский и заменит английскую фразу на выбранный язык.

Comment: Вам надо самому в теме вставлять строчки типа __() или _e(), затем все эти фразы добавить в ваш .po файл и перевести. Начальный перевод может сделать poedit, вам надо только проконтролировать, чтобы ошибок не было.

Comment: Добавил скрины, вроде все сделал как Вы говорите, но результат тот же

Comment: А что в вашем header.php на 43 строке делают слова text и domain? Должно быть _e('Archive of the day', 'pure');

Comment: Это редактор комментарии подставляет, на самом деле в коде их нет

Comment: Блин, тема fure, а в header.php pure написано.

Comment: Да, я это тоже заметил, потом поправил, но результат тот же